# Output font awesome svg icon inside div

Tags: html, svg, vector-graphics

I need to display a font awesome icon inside a div.
I've downloaded this icon from here https://fontawesome.com/icons/share-alt-square?style=solid
, then I opened the downloaded svg file with a text editor, copied data of `d` attribute and placed into my markup.

Final markup should look like this:

```
<div style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="32" height="32">
    <g>
      <rect width="64" height="64" fill=""></rect>
    </g>
    <g>
    <path d="M448 80v352c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H48c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V80c0-26.51 21.49-48 48-48h352c26.51 0 48 21.49 48 48zM304 296c-14.562 0-27.823 5.561-37.783 14.671l-67.958-40.775a56.339 56.339 0 0 0 0-27.793l67.958-40.775C276.177 210.439 289.438 216 304 216c30.928 0 56-25.072 56-56s-25.072-56-56-56-56 25.072-56 56c0 4.797.605 9.453 1.74 13.897l-67.958 40.775C171.823 205.561 158.562 200 144 200c-30.928 0-56 25.072-56 56s25.072 56 56 56c14.562 0 27.823-5.561 37.783-14.671l67.958 40.775a56.088 56.088 0 0 0-1.74 13.897c0 30.928 25.072 56 56 56s56-25.072 56-56C360 321.072 334.928 296 304 296z" fill="white"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I prefer such approach. Please correct me if I use it in a wrong way and it will not work.
In that case what would be the most appropriate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the path you are using is from an svg with a much bigger `viewBox`. So in order to adapt it to what you have you will need to change the `viewBox` of your svg.

In order to know what `viewBox` to use, you may use the `viewBox` of the original icon. An other way is getting the size and position of the bounding box (javascript method: `thePath.getBBox()`) of the path and use it to build the new value of the `viewBox`.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 32 448 448">
    <g>
      <rect y="32" width="448" height="448" fill=""></rect>
    </g>
    <g>
    <path id="thePath" d="M448 80v352c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H48c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V80c0-26.51 21.49-48 48-48h352c26.51 0 48 21.49 48 48zM304 296c-14.562 0-27.823 5.561-37.783 14.671l-67.958-40.775a56.339 56.339 0 0 0 0-27.793l67.958-40.775C276.177 210.439 289.438 216 304 216c30.928 0 56-25.072 56-56s-25.072-56-56-56-56 25.072-56 56c0 4.797.605 9.453 1.74 13.897l-67.958 40.775C171.823 205.561 158.562 200 144 200c-30.928 0-56 25.072-56 56s25.072 56 56 56c14.562 0 27.823-5.561 37.783-14.671l67.958 40.775a56.088 56.088 0 0 0-1.74 13.897c0 30.928 25.072 56 56 56s56-25.072 56-56C360 321.072 334.928 296 304 296z" fill="white"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```